# Return particular column value lag in MySQL

Tags: mysql

At the moment, I have the following table of values:

```
--------------------------------
|   ID  |    Action    | Time  |
--------------------------------
|   1   |    A         | 01    |    
|   1   |    BB        | 10    |
|   1   |    C         | 12    |
|   2   |    C         | 05    |
|   2   |    A         | 08    |
|   2   |    BB        | 17    |
|   2   |    A         | 26    |
|   2   |    BB        | 47    |
```

Assume that the data is arranged ascending by `Time`. 
What I want for each call, when the data is grouped by `ID`, to have a new column called `BB_Time` which has the time difference of BB and the previous event in the call, which would look like:

```
----------------------------
|   ID  |   ...   | BB_Time |
----------------------------
|   1   |   ...   |   09    |    
|   2   |   ...   |   21    |
```

If BB occurs at the start of a call, `BB_Time` would equal zero, and if BB occurs more than once in a call, the column should return the max time difference. 
EDIT: And if BB doesn't appear in a call, either NULL or 0 would work.

The closest(?) I've been able to crack this is limiting to just `BB` actions in the `WHERE` clause and tracking time that way, but that doesn't give a lag.

Thoughts?

Comment: How did you get ID 1, BB, BB_Time 09: If I would execute your algorithm as described I would get ID 1, BB,  BB_Time 10

Comment: what if the ID doesn't have a BB

Comment: @Norbert, BB gets prior row to diff, so 10-1=9

Comment: For ID=2, you had two BB actions.  Do you want the last or the max time gap

Comment: @DrewPierce Good Question -- Null or zero would be fine in this context

Comment: @Anon316 As the description states, return the max time.

Comment: So my answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people don't trust session variables, but I find as long as you are careful they are relatively reliable. Disclaimer: I believe MySQL does not officially have a defined order of evaluation for the evaluation of `SELECT` result fields. In practice it seems to always be from left to right, which this query relies on, however this is something to consider/re-evaluate whenever MySQL Server versions change. Also, I've seen other related questions on here which suggest this kind of query may not "play nice" with `VIEW`s.

```
SELECT ID, MAX(BB_Time) AS BB_Time
FROM (
   SELECT ID, `Action`
   , @prevID := IFNULL(@prevID, 0) AS prevID
   , IF(`Action`<>'BB'
        , 0
        , IF(@prevID<>ID, 0, `Time` - IFNULL(@prevTime, `Time`))
     ) AS BB_Time
   , @prevTime := `Time`
   , @prevID := ID
   FROM the_table
   ORDER BY ID, `Time`
) AS subQ
GROUP BY ID
;
```

*Updated to show all ID values, with 0 for IDs with no BB actions.*

Edit: Tested it with the sample data. First time it came back with 0's, second time it worked. Might need to initialize the @prev session variables to something before the select to be safe.

Comment: What was the error? Oh, updating the `ORDER BY` now.

Comment: no error. play it against your table til you get it

Comment: So thanks, this works in MySQL -- however, when I try importing to R using an RODBC connection, the BB_Time column has only zeros. 

Any thoughts on how to combat this, if possible?

Comment: R? Also, as I said in the Edit above, you might need to run something like these two queries (on the same connection) first `SET @prevID := -1;` and `SET @prevTime := -1;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a fiddle that works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7277/7), and here is the query...

```
set @lastTime:=0;
set @lastId:=0;
select newId, max(TimeGap) from
    (select (myTime - if(@lastId=id,@lastTime,0)) TimeGap,
            (@lastTime:=myTime) NewTime, action,
            (@lastId:=id) newId from myTable
        order by id, myTime) AllTimeGaps
 where action = 'BB' group by newId
```